# No "Extra Large icons" on High DPI laptop (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, icons, laptop-display, high-dpi

I have a high DPI laptop (3200×1800, 13" screen. Hardware is Lenovo Yoga2Pro), which I hate for [these](http://www.tested.com/tech/pcs/460553-problem-high-ppi-windows-display-scaling/) reasons.

My specific question is about the size of thumbnail icons in native Windows (10).

The "Large icons" setting in Windows
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) gives thumbnails of my photos which are 20 mm (3/4 inch) wide, i.e., too small to see (while using adapter scaling setting = "250% (recommended)").

Switching to the "Extra Large icons"
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) setting DOESN'T ALTER THE SIZE OF THE THUMBNAILS. All it does is space them apart more and change the wrapping parameters of the filename (the text wraps onto a second line at 44 characters, instead of 16).

I am on Windows 10 1511/10586.  I was hoping they might have fixed it, but no.  It was the same on version 8.1 of Windows.

I recently noticed that a proprietary app (by Canon) can see a bigger thumbnail size (56 mm wide), but only from within a "File>Open" dialog box.  So it must be possible.  Presumably this is what the native "Extra Large icons" view is supposed to look like.

How can I fix this in native Windows, please?   I know there are workarounds like changing the scaling factor or by using external apps to view thumbnails, but I'm tired of the extra overhead.

---

Graphics card specs below:

---

### System Information

```
         Operating System: Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit (10.0, Build 10586) (10586.th2_release_sec.151104-1948)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: LENOVO
             System Model: 20266
                     BIOS: 76CN38WW
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.4GHz
                   Memory: 8192MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 8104MB RAM
                Page File: 2873MB used, 7151MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
          DirectX Version: 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: 192 DPI (200 percent)
       System DPI Setting: 240 DPI (250 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: Enabled
                 Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.10586.0000 64bit Unicode
```

---

### DxDiag Notes

```
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.
```

---

### Display Devices

```
          Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family  
       Manufacturer: Intel Corporation  
          Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family  
           DAC type: Internal  
        Device Type: Full Device  
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_09  
     Display Memory: 4164 MB  
   Dedicated Memory: 112 MB  
      Shared Memory: 4052 MB  
       Current Mode: 3200 x 1800 (32 bit) (60Hz)  
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor  
      Monitor Model: unknown  
         Monitor Id: SDC424A  
        Native Mode: 3200 x 1800(p) (60.000Hz)  
        Output Type: Internal  
        Driver Name: igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd12umd64.dll, 
igdumdim32,igd10iumd32,igd10iumd32,igd12umd32  
Driver File Version: 10.18.0015.4240 (English)  
     Driver Version: 10.18.15.4240  
        DDI Version: 12  
     Feature Levels: 11.1,11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1  
       Driver Model: WDDM 2.0  
Graphics Preemption: Primitive  
 Compute Preemption: Thread group  
           Miracast: Supported  
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Integrated  
     Power P-states: Not Supported  
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail  
   Driver Date/Size: 16/06/2015 00:00:00, 36603096 bytes  
        WHQL Logo'd: n/a  
    WHQL Date Stamp: n/a  
  Device Identifier: {D7B78E66-4956-11CF-8A64-7719B4C2C735}  
          Vendor ID: 0x8086  
          Device ID: 0x0A16  
          SubSys ID: 0x397817AA  
        Revision ID: 0x0009  
 Driver Strong Name: oem102.inf:5f63e5341cc65b69:iHSWM_w10:10.18.15.4240:pci\ven_8086&dev_0a16&subsys_397817aa  
     Rank Of Driver: 00D10001  
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C ModeWMV9_C ModeVC1_C   
        DXVA2 Modes: <snip>
```

---

### System Devices

```
     Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Device ID: PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0A16&SUBSYS_397817AA&REV_09\3&11583659&0&10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if this will work. If you have a mouse connected, click a blank area on the desktop and hold ctrl + scroll up/down to make the icons bigger/smaller. I'm not sure how to replicate using the trackpad, but I just tested the ctrl+scroll on my PC and it worked for me. If not, will try and think of other troubleshooting steps :)

Comment: Hi
No, that's just another way of changing the 'icon size' settings (one could also use the Ribbon/menu or the shortcut key (Cntl+Shift+1, etc.)).  But it all leads to the same (unsuccessful) result described in the OP. 

ed: posters elsewhere have said that the max size supported within Explorer is 256x256, and it's just not possible to go any bigger without external sw